# Split Number by a number format

Tags: php

I truly thinking too long to find the logic/ algorithm to do this thing. Then I just use if else but I know this is bad because there will be too much statement.

I have number format group below to split the input number :

- 01 (Get 14 digits after this number format)
- 3101 (Get 6 digits after this number format)
- 3102 (Get 6 digits)
- 3202 (Get 6 digits)
- 13   (Get 6 digits)
- 15   (Get 6 digits)
- 11   (Get 6 digits)
- 21   (Get the rest)

**Some of rules** :

- 01 always in first sequence
- 21 always in last sequence
- other number format except 01 and 21 can be in any sequence position.
- The same prefix number format cannot be repeat

**example, Input Number :** **01**00690085173067**3102**002000**13**191004**21**191004091395

**The Result Should be :**

01 : 00690085173067
3102 : 002000
13 : 191004
21 : 191004091395

Currently I only use IF ELSE statement to get the digits after.

This is my pieces of code using PHP. This code can only handle that example input above. There will be possibility of other sequence number format as per rules, but it will difficult if only use if else statement like this.

```
$first = substr($input, 0, 2);
if ($first == 01) { 

    $itemCode =  substr($input, 2, 14); // get the 6 digits after 01
    $second = substr($input, 16, 4);

    if ($second == 3102) { 
        $quantity =  substr($input, 20, 6);  // get the 6 digits after 3102
        $third = substr($input, 26, 2);
        if ($third == 13) { 
           $packedDate =  substr($input, 28, 6); // get the 6 digits after 13
            $fourth = substr($input, 34, 2);  
            if ($fourth == 21) {
                $serialNumber =  substr($scanner, 36); // get the rest number after 21
            } 
       }
   }
}
```

Is there any good way to solve this thing?

Comment: What is meant by `21 always in last order`? It is always at the end given any input string?

Comment: @vivek_23 Just like my example input : **01**00690085173067**3102**002000**13**191004**21**191004091395
21 is always in last place

Comment: So, the string given as input will be always valid? What if we have something like `013201320213151121` ?

Comment: Hi @vivek_23. The main thing is I want to get the next digits after that number format (01, 3101, 3102, 3202, 13, 15, 11, 21).  Yes It possible if the input : **01**32013202131511**21**082918292

Comment: Yes, I know you need the next digits but we have overlapping issues here. Do you want to throw an exception if such an issue arises? Also, `3101` and `01` has `01` overlapped.

Comment: Your comment says `21 (Get 6 digits)` but in your expected output you have `21 : 191004091395` which has 12 digits

Comment: @vivek_23. I think we can handle it, because 01 is always in first sequence. so no need to check the 01 anymore. The other thing is We can get the length (I think). So after we get the 14 digits from (01), then find the other number format and get the length.

Comment: @nick oh sorry, I will update it

Comment: Will the input always be valid?

Comment: Can prefixes repeat? e.g. could you have `01....3102....3102....21.....`?

Comment: Hi @nick, No, same format cannot be repeat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the prefixes won't repeat, you can use `preg_match_all` to match the prefixes with each of their trailing digits, using `array_combine` to create arrays of digits indexed by their prefixes:

```
$input = '010069008517306731020020001319100421191004091395';

if (preg_match_all('/(01)(\d{14})|(310[12]|3202|1[135])(\d{6})|(21)(\d+)/', $input, $matches)) {
    $numbers = array_filter(array_combine($matches[1], $matches[2]) + 
                            array_combine($matches[3], $matches[4]) + 
                            array_combine($matches[5], $matches[6]));
    print_r($numbers);
}
else {
    echo "Invalid input!";
}
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [01] => 00690085173067
    [3102] => 002000
    [13] => 191004
    [21] => 191004091395
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/tSdeB)

Comment: It Works! so fast you answer my question. awesome. Thank you very much Nick :)